# Change theme in shiny app with authentification startup page

Tags: r, authentication, shiny, themes

I have a shiny R application in which I want to be able to change the theme. I have a navBar tab dedicated to this among other things.
To change the theme I have a selectInput allowing me to choose the theme I want. For this example, I've only used well-known themes, but I also have custom themes.

This application includes a login page at startup. Before adding this login page, changing the theme worked perfectly, but now it doesn't and I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
library(shinymanager)
library(bslib)
library(shiny)

Sys.setenv(LOGIN_USER = "a")
Sys.setenv(PWD_USER = "a")

cosmo = bslib::bs_theme(bootswatch = "cosmo", version = 5)
solar = bslib::bs_theme(bootswatch = "solar", version = 5)
yeti = bslib::bs_theme(bootswatch = "yeti", version = 5)

corresp = list("cosmo" = "cosmo",
               "solar" = "solar",
               "yeti" = "yeti")

login_pwd = function(){
  set_labels(
    language = "en",
    "Please authenticate",
    "Username:",
    "Password:",
    "Login",
    "Username or password are incorrect"
  )
}

ui = tagList(
  login_pwd(),

  navbarPage(
    theme = cosmo,
    inverse = F,
    windowTitle = "App",
    title = "App",
    id = "main_menu",
    
    tabPanel(
      title = "Themes",
      selectInput(
        inputId = "theme",
        "Themes :",
        c(
          "Cosmo" = "cosmo",
          "Solar" = "solar",
          "Yeti" = "yeti"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function( input, output, session ) {
  
  credentials <- data.frame(
    user = Sys.getenv("LOGIN_USER"),
    password = Sys.getenv("PWD_USER")
  )
  res_auth <- shinymanager::secure_server(
    check_credentials = shinymanager::check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  output$auth_output <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
  })
  
  
  observe(session$setCurrentTheme({
      get(corresp[[input$theme]])
  }))
  
}


shinyApp(
  shinymanager::secure_app(
    ui = ui,
    head_auth = login_pwd()
  ),
  # ui,
  server
)
```

I've tried adding a theme to the authentication page but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication routines prevent `input$theme` to take up a proper value. You should wrap it with `req` to ensure the observer fires only if it takes a truthy value:

```r
 observe(session$setCurrentTheme({
      get(corresp[[req(input$theme)]])
   }))
```